# Is it OK to contact the author of the paper for code review?

Tags: publications, etiquette, communication, code

I want to make sure that my code is OK and fully compliant with the original paper algorithm, is it OK to contact the professor that created the algorithm for reviewing my code?

Thanks

Comment: sure but why would this person spend some valuable time debugging *your* code?

Comment: What is the problem here: (a) the description of the algorithm in the original paper lacks some details (e.g., how normalization is performed), or (b) the algorithm is entirely clear and you just want to be sure you didn't introduce bugs? My answer would differ in the two cases.

Comment: both...................

Comment: @marcnicole (a) and (b) are incompatible alternatives (algorithm in paper is not clear, algorithm in paper is clear).

Comment: What have you done so far yourself to check your code? Have you tried replicating a result from the paper? Have you tested it on other data/input/parameters?

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is ok to ask, but don't expect much except in a couple of special cases. One case is if the professor is one in your own department, in which case they will probably assume some responsibility for your advancement.

Otherwise, you might be more successful if you have something to contribute to them that they would find valuable. If you propose a collaboration on an advance beyond their paper then you might have an opening.

For a student you might be able to have a local professor review the code, rather than the original author. This assumes that the person has an interest in that paper as well, I think.

But a blind ask for a code review is likely to be met with silence.